# Program goes into an infinite loop if a character is entered for a number in the input

Tags: visual-c++

I cant seem to get the error checking to work right for my GetInput phase.  I am trying to have that phase repeat until a number 1 -5 is put in there and nothing else. Thank You!

```
void GetInput(void)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 5: \n";
    cin >> OnetoFive;
    if (isdigit(OnetoFive) && (OnetoFive <= 5) && (OnetoFive >= 1))
    {
        return;
    }

    else 
    {
        system("cls");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "\n\nInvalid.  Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ";
        cin >> OnetoFive;
    }
}
```

Ok, now it works for alpha characters but the loop still wont work if I do a value over 5...it works one time, but the second time it just runs....any ideas

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you ask for input twice? Your loop should take care of that.

Secondly change you if condition to

```
   if (( isdigit(OnetoFive) && OnetoFive >= 1) && (OnetoFive <= 5))
```

You have to check if it's a digit as your first condition. Condition order counts!

Comment: ok, got condition checking good for alpha characters...now its numbers over 5 that are being a headache, any ideas?

Comment: Only not working the second time, right? The second time you ask you do not validate. You should -really- make a loop for validation and input.

Answer (score 0):

did you try replacing :

```
else 
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\n\nInvalid.  Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ";
    cin >> OnetoFive;
    if ((OnetoFive >= 1) && (OnetoFive <= 5) && isdigit(OnetoFive))
    {
        system("cls");
        return;
    }

}
```

with

```
else 
{
    GetInput();
}
```

Comment: My goodness, you guys are fast! I'm going to edit this bad boy and try again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not my strong side, but to get you an idea of how a loop suitable for your needs could look like:

```
bool GetInput()
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 5: \n";
    cin >> OnetoFive;

    if(isdigit(OnetoFive) && (OnetoFive <= 5) && (OnetoFive >= 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    else 
        {
        system("cls");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "\n\nInvalid.  Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ";
        }   
    return false;
}

while(!GetInput())
{
    GetInput();
}
```

Code written on my Android Phone so cannot guarantee it will work out of the box but it should give you an idea.